# MissingMethodException when using ConfigurationBuilder

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have a .NET Core 3.0 console application with the following segment of code:

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
```

When executed, the following exception is being thrown:

> System.MissingMethodException: 'Method not found:
>   'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2
>   Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfigurationBuilder.get_Properties()'.'

I have the following packages installed:

- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration (3.1.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions (1.0.0)
- Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json (1.0.0)

Any ideas what I'm missing here?

Comment: What version of the nuget packages are you using? It appears to work fine to 3.1.0 for me.

Comment: I updated my answer with the version numbers - I'm using 3.1.0 for the main Configuration one, and v1 for the FileExtensions and Json one. It appears I can upgrade the other two to 3.1, that is perhaps what the problem is.

Comment: @RyanThomas you're correct, this is what the problem is. If you add this as an answer I can mark it as the answer. Cheers! Not sure how I ended up installing the older versions.

Comment: Thanks, have added :) Glad it is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of the nuget packages are you using? It appears to work fine to 3.1.0 for me.

I imagine the older versions, caused something to be out of sync and one of those is referencing a field / property that no longer exists.